# Entity framework takes about 10 minutes to get data from Azure sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, sqlperformance

I have a Azure sql database in which i record chat logs that i later analyze. The query was fine at the beginning but currently it has around 11 million entries and it took me 586 second to get the data.

My model

```
public class Messages
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int ChannelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChannelId")]
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
```

Database call

```
                IEnumerable<Messages> messages = context.Messages.AsNoTracking()
                                     .Where(x => x.Channel.ChannelName == Channelname &&
                                     x.Timestamp > StartTime &&
                                     x.Timestamp < EndTime).ToArray();
```

Data once inserted is only read. I tried indexing timestamp column but didn't seem to help. Data is also sorted by datetime so i don't understand why it takes that long.

UPDATE:

I did some bechmarks

My way Channel.ChannelName == Channelname: 4:35

My way Channel.ChannelId == Id: 16sec

Suggested answer: 4:30

Suggested with id: 16 sec

sample was 40k results.

How do i fix this? Can i optimize more?

Comment: If you create a Stored Procedure and pass it the parameters do you get results quickly? The answer to that question will tell us whether to look in the DB or the code for answers.

Comment: Try running the generated SQL in sql manager, also run query analyzer against it

Comment: How many rows are in your result?

Comment: I'm doing some benchmarks now, from the looks of it 5 mins if Channel.ChannelName = "name", 16 seconds if Channel.ChannelId = id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Channel table have proper keys and indexes? Also try filtering properties that aren't external tables first (ex: Channel).

```
var messages = context.Messages.AsNoTracking()
         .Where(m => (m.Timestamp > StartTime) && (m.Timestamp < EndTime))
         .Where(x => x.Channel.ChannelName == Channelname)
         .ToArray();
```

Comment: hey, looks like you where right about keys part, how do i fix it?

Comment: first thing make sure your Id is flagged as Key on your Channel table. You can then try adding [Index] to the Id of each of your tables. I would also consider removing the [Index] from your Timestamp.